# Pandas dataframe: replace value with that of another column based on original value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where I want to replace the value in the Prediction column with the value in the column referred to by the prediction column.

| A | B | C | D | Prediction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stipulation | interrelation | jurisdiction | interpretation | D |
| typically | conceivably | tentatively | desperately | C |
| familiar | imaginative | apparent | logical | A |
| plan | explain | study | discard | B |

I have tried a few methods using df.apply() and map() but they haven't worked. The resulting dataframe would look like this:

| A | B | C | D | Prediction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stipulation | interrelation | jurisdiction | interpretation | interpretation |
| typically | conceivably | tentatively | desperately | tentatively |
| familiar | imaginative | apparent | logical | familiar |
| plan | explain | study | discard | explain |

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a dictionary for each row and return the key value of Prediction
df['val']=df.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict( )[x['Prediction']], axis=1)
df
```

```
     A          B             C             D              Prediction   val
0   stipulation interrelation jurisdiction  interpretation D            interpretation
1   typically   conceivably   tentatively   desperately    C            tentatively
2   familiar    imaginative   apparent      logical        A            familiar
3   plan        explain       study         discard        B            explain
```

Answer (score 0):

We used to have lookup ... but it had been removed. One work around

```
df['new'] = df.values[df.index,df.columns.get_indexer(df.Prediction)]
df
Out[318]: 
             A              B  ... Prediction             new
0  stipulation  interrelation  ...          D  interpretation
1    typically    conceivably  ...          C     tentatively
2     familiar    imaginative  ...          A        familiar
3         plan        explain  ...          B         explain
[4 rows x 6 columns]
```